# GitHub markdown shortcut to treat text as code?

Tags: github, keyboard-shortcuts, markdown

While writing an issue in a GitHub repository, how can I:

- Select a piece of text
- And press something so that it is treated as code?

For example, here in Stack Exchange I can select a piece of text and press "Ctrl + K" to mark it as code. If I do this in GitHub markdown, it will mark it as a URL instead.

[image: github markdown shortcut code]

Comment: *PS: There is a similar question to this one, but it treats code **formatting**, which is about spacing before the text.*

Comment: [Relevant](https://help.github.com/articles/using-keyboard-shortcuts/).

Answer (score 2):

In the GitHub editor, a button that looks like `<>` simply inserts a grave accent `` ` `` (also known as a "backtick") around the selected text. I don't see that there's a keyboard shortcut for it, though.

It seems far simpler to me to just add `` ` `` before and after your code block. (Which, incidentally, works the same way here.)

The [list of available GitHub keyboard shortcuts](https://help.github.com/articles/using-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Comment: Thanks @ale, I know how to do it manually, a pitty that there are no shortcuts for it, because I use it a lot.

Comment: I have contacted GitHub support, suggesting a keyboard shortcut for code.

Comment: This is a very dissatisfying answer. I too am looking for a keyboard shortcut for this. Stating that you find it simple not to use a shortcut is not an answer. People who ask this and search for this don't see it that way.

Comment: @LucasBustamante did you get any feedback?